# Is it possible to use DocuSign conditional tabs to suppress whole pages?

Tags: templates, tags, docusignapi

I have a DocuSign template with two pages.  At the top of the first page I have a check box that says "are you 18 or over?".  If the check box is checked, I want the second page to be hidden.  If it is not checked, I want the first page to be hidden.

I know this is possible with individual tabs/tags, but I'd like to know if it can be done with whole pages.  Do "composite templates" present any sort of solution for this?

Comment: It is not possible to do this, although it's a pretty great idea. I would recommend sending out the envelope, then view the fields upon completion. Then based off of the value of the "are you 18 or over?" field, send an additional envelope with that extra document.

Comment: That's an idea.  But I think we'll just control it in the front end,  and collect age information about the documents before we serve up the documents.